# How to create multiple Extent Report for multiple testclass

Tags: c#, selenium

```
I have different Test classes in different Testfiles, I want to create different Extent reports for each test files, right now only one report is generated which is overridden. I am using AventStack.ExtentReports.
```

This is extent manager class which contains a path and other specific credentials
    public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
            public static ExtentReports extent;

```
        public ExtentManager()
        {

        }
        public static ExtentReports GetInstance()
        {
            if (extent == null)
            {

                string reportpath = "\\Reports\\Report.html";

                htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportpath);
                htmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = Theme.Dark;

                extent = new ExtentReports();
                extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);

                extent.AddSystemInfo("Host Name", "ABC");
                extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "Test QA");
                extent.AddSystemInfo("Username", "XYZ");

                htmlReporter.LoadConfig("extent-config.xml"); //Get the config.xml file 
            }
            return extent;
        }
public testclass1
{
     ExtentReports rep;
     ExtentTest test;
     public testclass()
     {
        rep = ExtentManager.GetInstance();
      }
   public void TestMethod1()
          {
            test = rep.CreateTest("LoginPage");
            test.Log(Status.Info, "Starting test");
            //My Login method to login in the app
            rep.flush();
           }
 }

public testclass2
{
    ExtentReports rep;
     ExtentTest test;
     public testclass()
     {
        rep = ExtentManager.GetInstance();
      }
   public void TestMethod2()
          {
            test = rep.CreateTest("userblock");
            test.Log(Status.Info, "Starting test");
            //My userblockmethod
            rep.flush();
           }
}
```

//creates one report which overrides it and give report of last executed testclass
Result--
testclass1Report.html
testclass2Report.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrange your code as I made here, it will help you to create the multiple test in the single extent report.
```

**Step 1:** Your XML should be as a:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        Console.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM \"[9](http:\">");
        Console.WriteLine("<suite name=\"Suite\">");
        Console.WriteLine("  <test name=\"Test1\">");
        Console.WriteLine("    <classes>");
        Console.WriteLine("      <class name=\"TestPackage.TestClass1\"/>");
        Console.WriteLine("      <class name=\"TestPackage.TestClass2\"/>");
        Console.WriteLine("    </classes>");
        Console.WriteLine("  </test>");
        Console.WriteLine("  <test name=\"Test2\">");
        Console.WriteLine("    <classes>");
        Console.WriteLine("      <class name=\"TestPackage.TestClass3\"/>");
        Console.WriteLine("      <class name=\"TestPackage.TestClass4\"/>");
        Console.WriteLine("    </classes>");
        Console.WriteLine("  </test>");
        Console.WriteLine("</suite>");
    }
}

**
```

**Step 2:**

Create one extent report class:

```
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;

public class ExtentReporter
{
    public static ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static ExtentTest test;

    public static void SetUp()
    {
        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./Reports/Extent_Report.html");
        htmlReporter.Config.DocumentTitle = "Selenium Test Report";
        htmlReporter.Config.ReportName = "Selenium Test Report";
        htmlReporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Standard;
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.SetSystemInfo("OS", "Windows 10");
        extent.SetSystemInfo("Browser", "Chrome");
    }

    public static void TearDown()
    {
        extent.Flush();
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**
In each test class, use the @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod annotations to start and end the test instance for each test method and log the test status and details.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using NUnit.Framework;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Status;

public class TestClass1 : ExtentReporter
{
    IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUpMethod()
    {
        test = extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestGoogleTitle()
    {
        string title = driver.Title;
        Assert.AreEqual(title, "Google");
        test.Log(Status.Pass, "Title verified");
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestGoogleLogo()
    {
        IWebElement logo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("hplogo"));
        Assert.IsTrue(logo.Displayed);
        test.Log(Status.Pass, "Logo verified");
    }
}

using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using System.IO;

public class ClassName
{
    private ExtentTest test;
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [AfterMethod]
    public void TearDownMethod(ITestResult result)
    {
        if (result.Status == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            test.Log(Status.Fail, "Test Case Failed is " + result.Name);
            test.Log(Status.Fail, "Test Case Failed is " + result.Throwable);
            string screenshotPath = GetScreenshot(driver, result.Name);
            test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
        }
        else if (result.Status == ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            test.Log(Status.Skip, "Test Case Skipped is " + result.Name);
        }
        driver.Quit();
    }

    public static string GetScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, string screenshotName)
    {
        string dateName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        ITakesScreenshot ts = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;
        Screenshot screenshot = ts.GetScreenshot();
        string destination = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Screenshots", screenshotName + dateName + ".png");
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(destination, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        return destination;
    }
}
```

**Step 4:**  Run the testng.xml file as TestNG Suite.